# How can I pass the string value inside the Range as a reference?

Tags: excel, vba

I have one Excel Datasheet which consists of details about a particular product. Here I have written a VB script which pinpoints to a particular product using the unique product name which I have assigned for all the individual products.
When I run the below code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton23_Click()
Dim rngX As Range
Dim num As String

Set rngX = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10000").Find("CTPT",     lookat:=xlPart)
num = rngX.Address
Range("$A$13:B" & Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row).Copy
Range("F1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

End Sub
```

[image]

Here in the above code I am getting where the Product "CTPT" is located, the address of the cell location is stored in "num".
 How can I assign the "num" cell address $A$13 in the range function so that I can select all the parameters related to that particular product and it will get copied and pasted in F1 cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in that you will start with the `rngX` that was located with the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx), but you do not need to resolve that to a [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) that is subsequently used to reference a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx). Using `rngX` as a Range.Object can generate the starting cell and `rngX.Row` can help get the lower left cell of the [Range.Copy method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760.aspx).

```
Private Sub CommandButton23_Click()
    Dim rngX As Range
    Dim num As String

    Set rngX = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10000").Find("CTPT", lookat:=xlPart)
    Range(rngX, Range("B" & rngX.Row).End(xlDown)).Copy
    Range("F1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jeeped!

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
Range(num & ":B" & Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row).Copy
```

Or, without the intermediary `num` variable:

```
Range(rngX.Address & ":B" & Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row).Copy
```

I would advise that `Range("B2").End(xlDown)` may not be ideal, it is particularly unreliable when working on data with non-contiguous areas as in your screenshot.

Comment: Thanks a ton David! it worked!!
Since i am new to the VBA i was struggling with the above problem.
Thanks Once again, have a good day ahead!

Comment: I'm curious why `Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row` doesn't stop at row 11.

Comment: @Jeeped I would expect it to stop at 12 (if not sooner, some rows are hidden in the screenshot), hence my caveat that method is "unreliable" at best.  If all OP needs is columns A and B, then I would just do `rngX.Resize(1,2)`, but if OP actually needs "last row", then there are other more reliable approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba